# UNIX redirect tty to c++ stdin in different terminal

Tags: terminal, pipe, stdin, tty, io-redirection

I have a simple command line c++ program shown below that takes stdin from the command line. I have 2 SSH terminals open on my Mac. One is /dev/ttys001 and one is /dev/ttys000. I want to echo a value in one terminal and have it be used at the stdin in the second terminal using my program. I can't seem to achieve this. What is the proper syntax? Thanks -

I've tried variations of the following but with no luck. In the terminal where I am running ./test, it prompts for the number and the echo from the other terminal definitely shows up on the console but it is not perceived by the program as stdin?

TERMINAL 1:

```
./test < /dev/ttys001
```

TERMINAL 2:

```
echo 2 > /dev/ttys001
```

My program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int nb;
    cin>>nb;
    cout << "Here is your number:" << nb << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain you can do it that way. However, you can use a named pipe. On terminal 1:

```
mkfifo mypipe

myprogram < mypipe
```

Then on terminal 2:

```
echo > mypipe
```

Then type away. But your code looks like it will only execute once and then terminate, so you may want to add a loop.

Comment: thanks for the response - when I do './test < mypipe' I lose my prompt to input a number and if I do 'echo 2 > mypipe' from the second terminal my program doesn't do anything, or terminate. Any thoughts??

Comment: Thanks , this worked in Linux ( Ubuntu ) at least... just not my Mac.

Comment: That's odd because I tested it on my Mac running Mountain Lion.